# Regular Expression 65 CPL and No Word Breaks

Tags: regex, openoffice.org

I'm trying to perfect a regular expression to take paragraphs of text and arrange them with a 65 character per line limit, and specifically not to split any words.

I'm using Apache OpenOffice to Find and Replace.
My Find expression:

```
(.{1,65}\s)
```

My Replace expression:

```
$1\n
```

Oddly the Find expression looks to do what I want on https://regex101.com/ but not in OpenOffice.
I've also tried in Notepad++ and that too doesn't produce the same result as regex101.com.

In OpenOffice it seems to leave out the last word of each line.
If I change my Find expression to (.{1,65}) that works, but then splits up words which I can't have.

Here's a chunk of sample text;

> Why do we use it?
> It is a long established fact that a reader will be
> distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its
> layout.

I'm no expert in Regular Expressions so any assistance is greatly appreciated.
Also open to other methods than OpenOffice Find and Replace.

**Update-01:**
So it seems to be that my Find expression only does what I need when there are soft line breaks (shift+enter) but not hard line breaks (enter).

If anyone knows how I can perfect the expression to behave the same for hard line breaks that'd be ideal. Alternatively I'm looking into how to replace hard line breaks with soft line breaks. OpenOffice does actually support this but the other way around - if I Find `\n` and Replace with `\n` it will replace soft line breaks with hard line breaks. I'm looking to do it the other way around though.

Comment: It worked for me in AOO 4.1.6. Be sure to select Regular Expressions under More Options. Also, please make the example much smaller (it looks like about 5 words should be enough to demonstrate this problem), and then show the result you experienced along with the desired result. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @JimK So it seems to be something to do with the carriage return or the new line. If you copy that text straight from above and paste into OpenOffice it does actually work. But if you copy that text and put into a .txt file (via terminal or textedit on Mac) it then will produce different results. I'm quite stumped there, as I thought a .txt file would remove any formatting. When you paste the unformatted text (.txt) into OpenOffice it does also seem to have more of a gap on the new line after the question. Going to keep investigating, will update if I figure out why.

Comment: Furthermore to this, it seems to be the difference between paragraph breaks and line breaks. I'm now trying to figure out how to replace paragraph breaks with line breaks.

Comment: To work with different types of line breaks, use [AltSearch](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer).

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using NoteTab Light as the built-in Find and Replace treats the regular expressions and line breaks as we needed.

I wasn't unable to get AltSearch to work with these expressions, but honestly didn't spend too much time on it either.